# Java IRC ping request

Tags: java, ping, irc

I wanna connect to IRC through my own Java client, but there is a problem

Whenever IRC server sends me ping request like PING :6E17BFF I must return this PONG :6E17BFF

You can see the code I'm using below. Have I'm doing something wrong?

Each time when I'm connecting I receive this

```
NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
NOTICE AUTH :*** Couldn't resolve your hostname; using your IP address instead
PING :6E17BFF
PONG :6E17BFF
ERROR :Closing Link: TestNick[ipaddress] (Ping timeout: 33 seconds)
```

I hope you can help me

Code

```
while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if(line.substring(0,4).equals("PING")){
            writer.write("PONG :"+line.substring(6)+"\n\r");
            System.out.println("PONG :"+line.substring(6));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't solve your problems, but if you want to make life easier you can use the functionality in https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/. Source code is also provided there.

Comment: Could it be that your PONG message is not really being send? [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush%28%29)

Comment: remove the \n\r .. why are you assuming that you have to put \n\r at the end, also the order is \r\n, CR LF not LF CR, try just \n

Comment: **Solved** The problem was in replacing \n instead of \n\r

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to handle Ping / Pong in a teaching bot.  As you will see I left my test responses in place that I used to verify that the process was working.

```
//****************************************************************************** 
//PING PONG Handler and while loop test. Tests to be removed before full implementation
//******************************************************************************
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println("<--" + line);
        if (line.startsWith("PING")) {
         //sendPrivmsg("#Test", "The server just PINGED!");
          //sendPrivmsg("#Test", "Yes, and it was answered with a PONG!");
            writeLine(line.replace("PING", "PONG"));
             //sendPrivmsg("#Test", "This is a private message to channel #Test Pong Pong Pong Pong Pong");
        }
```